# Cannot run this React Native example in web browser

Tags: javascript, react-native

Code example I am trying to run: https://github.com/nshaposhnik/react-native-maps-example

I am on windows 10.

What I do:

- Downloaded the code
- Extracted to folder
- Setup with the following after deleting yarn.lock:

  yarn add react-native-maps

  yarn add react-native-maps-directions

  yarn add react-native-google-places-autocomplete

  npm install

  npm audit fix
- Edit the code in the 3 places that requires my custom google API key which I got from the developer site
- Tried running via:

  npm start

I get a successful run in the terminal (" Welcome to React Native! Learn once, write anywhere"), but no browser opens up. I go to `localhost:8081` in my browser and see a barren webpage with the following text:

```
React Native packager is running.

Visit documentation
```

That's all. Nothing in the sample project runs. I just want to run their app in a browser or emulator, though I don't have any of the phone emulators working, so I just want to run in web browser.

How can I make this work from the above example? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run emulator separately on "Windows" using android studio or command line, and after open your project using VsCode(or your editor) and the run following command ,

react-native run-android

Your app will run on your opened emulator